# How to determine what caused this crack on the wall?

Tags: drywall, crack

All of a sudden this morning I saw about a 14 foot crack on a wall facing the outside (no neighbours) and I'm freaking out. I'm sure I would have noticed it before.  The fact that it probably appeared overnight worries me. Should be I concerned or is just a cosmetic problem?

Background: it's a condo which is only 1.5 years old on the 17th floor.  It's been -14 to -20 °C (7 to -4 °F) for weeks if that helps.

It seems to be a very superficial crack in the paint but I have never seen something like it.  The crack is a straight line starting 2 feet below the ceiling and goes in a straight line down.  I'm  used to seeing cracks that are crooked.

Is this type of crack common and what is the cause?  Does it require professional help?  Is the place going to crack?  How do I find out the cause?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a crack in the seam between two pieces of drywall. This is not very unusual and, by itself, is not an indication of serious structural damage. However, if there were structural damage,it might first appear this way. Is there any sign of cracking or shifting on the outside of this wall?

Comment: That's Celsius temperature, right?

Comment: yes, Celsius. @User58220

Comment: I'm on the 17th floor of a building. Can't see outside.

Comment: Does structural damage mean the wall can fall off?

Comment: @bib: should it be left alone or do these kind of things need to be fixed if it's just drywall issues?

Comment: Impossible to say for sure. You should report it to building management and have them inspect it. Structural can range from minor to serious, but a wall falling off is rare.

Comment: I'm shocked about the fact that is a possiblity it could be structural...supposed to be quality builder Tridel...thought buying new means no worries.  :-(

Comment: @bib: could it spread to peolle living above and below you?  I was supposed to go abroad  tonight so  do I have to be worried?  How about spreading?  Do drywall only cracks get bigger or just stay the same?

Comment: In general, drywall cracks are limited to the 4x8 panel involved and do not spread. The only thing that could affect people above and below are major building issues that you cannot control. Call management. They will either take responsibility with a structural problem or tell you its cosmetic and put your mind at ease.

Comment: 4×8 inches?  Yes, I do want to do that but first I have to move stuff out of their way but I have to wait for help.  Too heavy. Is it surprising this might have come overnight?

Answer (score 1):

Cracks are almost always caused by shifting, vibrations or impacts.  Cracks in walls that are perfectly straight usually follow a seam where two pieces of drywall meet.  If the crack is just in the paint or the drywall then its unlikely itself to be a structural problem though there might be a more serious underlying problem.

Assuming it is drywall here, repairing it is the same as any other drywall repair - mud, sand, paint.

Comment: Hmmmm..this reminds me...for the last few days the people living above me have been making noise like hammering or something...could it be the vibrations from their stuff caused it?

Comment: Very possible that could be the cause.

Comment: Could it have caused it: yes.  Was it their "fault": no.  Moderate hammering would not itself be enough unless the original install was weak.

Answer (score 1):

If this is also a very new building, quite possibly the building is settling.  Don't forget, after you add all the drywall to a building frame, it becomes extremely heavy and starts settling into the ground, and depending on how large the building is, different parts may settle at different rates.